# Creation of see through portal in SceneKit

Tags: ios, macos, scenekit, arkit

What I'm trying to achieve is a see through "portal" using `SceneKit`. I have two basic requirements for it:

- While moving around it user should be able to see scene inside a portal by different angles
- It should be thin "2D" levitating in the air portal

My approach is to create a `.dae` file with hollowed sphere and than add two textures to it - transparent onto the outside surface and non transparent textured inside, so the user can look through hole and see the inner contents. But I'm struggling to do so because basically making the outer texture transparent makes the inner visible. After hours of searching the web I still don't have any answer. How is functionality like this achieved?

---

Portals like this are pretty common in a different kind of games, so there is gotta be some basic technique to achieve this.

Comment: It’s most likely all about cameras. Try to find out how to project what a camera sees onto some node. Maybe that works...

Comment: Thanks, I will try to work in this direction. However, I still hope there are some materials on the theme.